# Problemas padding MENU CSS

Tags: jquery, css, padding

Estou com um pequeno problema estético em 1 menu dropdown.

O problema é o seguinte, eu aumente o padding no CSS (bottom e top) e a alteração só ocorre no último "li" do menu.

Já fiz várias tentativas e não encontrei onde poderia mudar. Queria que os submenus ficassem mais espaçados.

Link do menu: https://jsfiddle.net/L1L64dpf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frederico foi preciso Fazer alguns ajustes no CSS, deixei os comentário no código, mas basicamente vc tem que ajustar o `padding`, mas tem que lembrar de ajustar o `height` nas `LI` também. Basicamente é isso. Mas vc tb precisa ajustar a alturas dos + e - dos botões para eles ficarem centralizas. *(já fiz isso, mas se vc quiser aumentar mais vc vai precisar centralizar novamente, tb deixei isso comentado no CSS)*

Veja como ficou no código abaixo

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700);
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a,
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
#cssmenu{z-index:1000;}
#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu > ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.cssmenu{
 background: #003642;
}
#cssmenu #menu-button {
  display: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  background: #003642;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul {
  font-size: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 25px 17px;
  font-size: 12px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #04b1a1;
  transition: all .5s linear;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 29px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 26px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #fff;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 23px;
  height: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li {
  height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
}
#cssmenu.align-right li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    /* Ajuste de altura do Height */
  height: 55px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.15);
  padding: 21px 15px; /* Ajuste de altura do Padding*/
  width: 230px;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: #003642;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.last-item > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li a:hover {
 background-color:#04b1a1;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  right: 11px;
  width: 8px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 11px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  right: 14px;
  display: block;
  width: 2px;
  height: 8px;
  background: #dddddd;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: all .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: all .25s ease;
  -ms-transition: all .25s ease;
  -o-transition: all .25s ease;
  transition: all .25s ease;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul li.has-sub > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: 14px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub:hover > a:before {
  top: 17px;
  height: 0;
}
@media all and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (max-width: 1024px), only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  *:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 17px;
  }
  #cssmenu.align-center > ul {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li,
  #cssmenu li:hover > ul > li {
    height: auto;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    float: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 25px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
    padding-left: 35px;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li a {
    color: #dddddd;
    background: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
  #cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul,
  #cssmenu ul ul ul,
  #cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
  }
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu > ul > li.has-sub > a:before,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:after,
  #cssmenu ul ul > li.has-sub > a:before {
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button {
    display: block;
    padding: 17px;
 top:10px;
    color: #dddddd;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 4px;
    width: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid #dddddd;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 17px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 20px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:after {
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 15px;
    background: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu #menu-button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #ffffff;
    width: 15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(120, 120, 120, 0.2);
    height: 46px;
    width: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened {
    background: #262626;
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button {
      /* aumentar o height */
    height: 54px;
    width: 34px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 19px;
    width: 8px;
    height: 2px;
    display: block;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:after {
    top: 28px;
    right: 13px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:after {
    background: #ffffff;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 19px;
    right: 22px;
    display: block;
    width: 2px;
    height: 8px;
    background: #dddddd;
    content: '';
  }
  #cssmenu ul ul .submenu-button:before {
    top: 25px;
    right: 16px;
  }
  #cssmenu .submenu-button.submenu-opened:before {
    display: none;
  }
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id='cssmenu'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="/index" target="_self">Inicial</a></li>
          <li><a href="/#" target="_self">Institucional</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="/cooperativismo-1" target="_self">Cooperativismo</a></li>
            <li><a href="/#" target="_self">O Sicoob Coopcredi</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="/quem-somos" target="_self">Quem Somos</a></li><li><a href="/missao-visao-e-valores" target="_self">Missão, visão e valores</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" target="_blank">Responsabilidade socioambiental</a></li>
             </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

      <script>
      (function($) {

$.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
    
    var cssmenu = $(this), settings = $.extend({
      title: "Menu",
      format: "dropdown",
      sticky: false
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      cssmenu.prepend('<div id="menu-button">' + settings.title + '</div>');
      $(this).find("#menu-button").on('click', function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
        var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
        if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) { 
          mainmenu.hide().removeClass('open');
        }
        else {
          mainmenu.show().addClass('open');
          if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
            mainmenu.find('ul').show();
          }
        }
      });

      cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');

      multiTg = function() {
        cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
        cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
          $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
          if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
            $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').hide();
          }
          else {
            $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').show();
          }
        });
      };

      if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
      else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');

      if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');

      resizeFix = function() {
        if ($( window ).width() > 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').show();
        }

        if ($(window).width() <= 768) {
          cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
        }
      };
      resizeFix();
      return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);

    });
};
})(jQuery);

(function($){
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#cssmenu").menumaker({
 title: '<a href="index.php" target="_self"><img src="images/logo2.png" style="margin-top:-20px;" alt="o"></a>',
 format: "multitoggle"
});

});
})(jQuery);
      </script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu o problema. Muito obrigado

Comment: Tranquilo jovem tmj